# Update sql in perl script - execute statement stuck

Tags: sql, perl, sql-update, prepared-statement, execute

Getting something is wrong with the execute statement.  It just seems to hang forever when I run in command prompt.  It doesn't die either.  does execute maybe need parameters?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

$dbh = DBI->connect('DB', 'NAME', 'PASS',{ LongReadLen => 1000000} ) or die 'Error: cant connect to db';

$st= "update table set the_id = 7 where mid = 23 and tid = 22";

my $UpdateRecord = $dbh->prepare($st)  or die "Couldn't prepare statement: $st".$dbh->errstr;
$UpdateRecord->execute() or die "can not execute $UpdateRecord".$dbh->errstr;
$UpdateRecord->finish;


$dbh->disconnect();
```

EDIT:
I tried binding in execute as well as using bind_param(), and it's still hanging up.

Comment: Is it getting stuck on the `execute` or on the `finish`?

Comment: check your connection string, what db type are you using?

Comment: No, `execute` doesn't require a parameter unless there are placeholders in the SQL statement. I can't see anything wrong with that except that there's no point in display the value of `$UpdateRecord` as it is just a reference to a statement handle and will appear as something like `DBI::st=HASH(0x2dcfd4c)`. From your use of `LongReadLen` I assume you're using a MySQL database? How big is `table` and do you expect more than one row as a result?

Comment: you have a table named table?

Comment: @mob  It's getting stuck on execute.  When I comment out finish it still hangs up

Comment: @Borodin It's oracle DB.  It's a table with 6million records..and I only will get one record back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a `do` instead of `prepare`.

```
my $UpdatedRecord = $dbh->do($st)  or die "Statement fails: $st".$dbh->errstr;
```

[From DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#do):

> This method is typically most useful for non-SELECT statements that
>   either cannot be prepared in advance (due to a limitation of the
>   driver) or do not need to be executed repeatedly. It should not be
>   used for SELECT statements because it does not return a statement
>   handle (so you can't fetch any data).

Also it's always better to add/use db driver module,the one you are using, at top after `use DBI;` statement.

`use DBD::Oracle`;

Also add

> use strict;
>   use warnings;

Comment: I tried do and did the same thing.  However, not sure how to implement your other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I locked a bunch of objects from failing to put the disconnect in before I ran it once...yeah, don't do that.